# How to get data in many to many relationship and return AsQueryable in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

How I can get book `AsQueryable` with category name in `bookParams`?

It can be implemented in any way as long as it returns `AsQueryable` to I can do pagination.

Thanks for any help.

**BookService.cs**

```
public async Task<PagedList<Book>> GetBooksAsync(BookParams bookParams)
{ 
    var query = repository.context.Books.AsQueryable();
            
    // query to get books with category name
    return await PagedList<Book>.CreateAsync(query, bookParams.pageNumber, bookParams.pageSize);
}
```

**Book.cs**

```
public class Book: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}
```

**Category.cs**

```
public class Category: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}
```

**BookCategory.cs**

```
public class BookCategory: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```